# Properties of infrasound of our muscles?

Tags: acoustics, biology

I have read, that some animals (like cats) are able to hear other animals (like humans) staying still by percepting infrasound, emmited by their muscles.

Is this true?

I know, muscles are really [have a tonus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscle_tone), i.e. they vibrate even if idle. But how powerful infrasound it can cause? Infrasound should have very long waves, is it possible to emit such waves with muscles?

How these sounds can be detected, if exist?

I wonder, if it can be used as presence detector? Even it is probably possible to identify personality or sleep or awake state by spectrum analysis.

Comment: Source ? Are you sure it's not the infrasound at contact of floor, object, and air ?

Comment: Detection can be by better ear, by pressure on skin and bones, or for many mamals, on mustache hairs.
PS: New Capcha box not working :-( :-( :-(

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET I have no serious sources, this why I am asking.

Answer (score -1):

Detection can be by better ear, by pressure on skin and bones, or for many mamals, on mustache hairs.

Comment: as usual for downvoters: if you think something is false, point it out. Consider also that you might not have understood the point (for various reasons, including the phrasing of the answer): pointing out would confirm or infirm your 1st feeling.